# Jackson XmlMapper how to serialize a list with dynamic tag name

Tags: java, jaxb, xml-serialization, jackson-dataformat-xml

So I'm trying to serialize a java object with a list to an xml file but the problem with the format that I'm trying to do is it requires the list to have dynamic element names.

I'm trying to do something like this,

```
<element>
     <child-element-1 attr1="testing1">
     <child-element-2 attr2="testing2">
     <child-element-1 attr1="testing1">
     <child-element-2 attr2="testing2">
     .
     .
     .
</element>
```

where child-element-1 and child-element-2 are alternating and can repeat n number of times.
also note that it's possible that I add more elements that can be included in this list say for example `<child-element-3 attr3="testing3">` something like that.

any ideas?

Comment: Alternating XML elements like that is really a badly designed XML, so if at all possible, you should re-design the XML so each pair of child elements are wrapped in an intermediate element.

Comment: yeah i thought so too. it's a format that the company has grown accustomed to. i don't think they'll change the requirements. oh well.